# Test if ValidationError was raised

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to test if an exception was raised how can I do that?

in my models.py I have this function, the one I want to test:

```
  def validate_percent(value):
    if not (value >= 0 and value <= 100):
      raise ValidationError('error')
```

in my tests.py I tried this:

```
def test_validate_percent(self):
    self.assertRaises(ValidationError, validate_percent(1000))
```

the output of the test is:

```
..E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_validate_percent (tm.tests.models.helpers.HelpersTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/...py", line 21, in test_validate_percent
    self.assertRaises(ValidationError, validate_percent(1000))
  File "/....py", line 25, in validate_percent
    raise ValidationError(u'error' % value)
ValidationError: ['error']
```

Comment: Note that in Python your validation check should be written `if not 0 <= value <= 100`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`assertRaises` is used as a context manager:

```
def test_validate_percent(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        validate_percent(1000)
```

or with a callable:

```
def test_validate_percent(self):
    self.assertRaises(ValidationError, validate_percent, 1000)
```

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

Comment: Using assertRaises as a context manager was added in Python 2.7, so it's not available on Python 2.6 or older - such as when using the system installed Python on CentOS 5.x.  This bit me integrating unittests into the RPM build process on CentOS 5.7.

Comment: unbelievable :)

Comment: In my case had to use the [context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3166985/5675325).

Answer (score 3):

```
def test_validate_percent(self):
    self.assertRaises(ValidationError, validate_percent, 1000)
```