# assertRaises not catching IntegrityError , Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, sqlalchemy, assert

My test is not catching psycopg2.IntegrityError with assertRaises. I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy.

```
def test_insert_cash_flow(self):
    cf = CashFlow()
    db.session.add(cf)
    self.assertRaises(psycopg2.IntegrityError, db.session.commit)
```

My CashFlow SQLAlchemy model has several nullable=False fields. It says my tests failed and IntegrityError is printed to the screen but my assertRaises does not catch this. Does anyone have any suspicion why?

Comment: Strange ... indeed. Have you try to use self.assertRaises within a with statement, has outlined in the documentation? https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

Comment: Are you sure you have `db.session.commit` and not `db.session.commit()`?

Comment: Related or duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19289291/771848.

Comment: Yes I have tried using the with statement, with the same failure. And yes I am sure I have db.session.commit without ()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQLAlchemy raises `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError`, which wraps the underlying exception, not the exception from the database driver.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: user.name [SQL: 'INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES (?)'] [parameters: (None,)]
```

Test for the correct exception.

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
self.assertRaises(IntegrityError, db.session.commit)
```