# How to test invalid record insertion with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

How can I write a unit test to confirm that inserting an invalid record fails with SQLAlchemy/Postgres? I'm currently doing this:

```
session.add(invalid_record)
session.flush()
query = list(session.query(Article).filter_by(
                record_id=invalid_record.record_id,
            ))
assert len(query) == 0
```

But this fails when I try and add the invalid record (violating a Not Null constraint).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `assertraises` if you are using `unittest`, see this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28223420/5982697

So something like:

```
with self.assertRaises(sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError):
    session.add(invalid_record)
```

Assuming it raises an `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError`.

EDIT: capitalize the `R`

Comment: Isn't it [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) with a capital R?