# Find Type Of Exception

Tags: python, exception, testing, assertion

I have made a class (derived from `Exception`):

```
class InvalidFilterException(Exception):
      #some code here
      super().__init__(message)
```

Now, when I run tests on this module, using `unittest.Testcase` , running

`assertRaises(Exception, InvalidFilterException, arg1, arg2)`

Gives an Error:

`AssertionError: Exception not raised by InvalidFilterException`

Can someone tell me what should I put in place of `Exception` as the first argument in `assertRaises`so that this test passes?
I also tried using `InvalidFilterException`, as the argument, but that failed too, with the same output.

Comment: Your test makes no sense. An exception doesn't raise another exception. You should test that your actual code under test raises InvalidFilterException.

Comment: is it because you don't `raise` the exception, only `__init__` it?

Comment: @No changes to the first argument will make that test pass. What do you want to assert actually?

Comment: @Stael Whenever i call `InvalidFilterException`, I call it like: `raise InvalidFilterException(arg1,arg2)`

Comment: Then *that* is the code you should be testing.

Comment: @Goyo I want to run tests on this module. The first argument should be the type of error that is raised when the function(arg1,arg2) is run, I am not able to pass the test even after passing the type of Exception

Comment: @DanielRoseman How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean? You write a test that calls the code that raises the exception, and wrap it in `assertRaises`.

Comment: @AyushShridhar I don't understand what you wat, naybe post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are trying to InvalidFilterException because the second argument to assertRaises is callable that you want to test.

You need to use your exception like...

```
assertRaises(InvalidFilterException, do_something, arg1, arg2)
```

or

```
with assertRaises(InvalidFilterException):
    do_something(arg1, arg2)
```

do_something is your function or callable that needs to be tested.

Comment: What exactly will the `do_something()` function do? As far as I know, the test will pass if `InvalidFilterException`  is raised when `do_something(arg1,arg2)` is run.

Comment: Yes .. so the function or block of code that you want to test will be do_something

Comment: You can refer to this link for more information... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129507/how-do-you-test-that-a-python-function-throws-an-exception?rq=1