# Python Testing raised Value Error

Tags: python

I am just using the regular library ( not pytest) and trying to confirm a ValueError.

test:

```
data = get_time_zone("sun/10-21 tz:US/Eas2tern")
```

Result:

```
if zone not in pytz.all_timezones:
    raise ValueError("Invalid Time Zone Used: " + time_zone)

>>> ValueError: Invalid Time Zone Used: US/Eas2tern
```

I would like to test it with a similar structure;

```
Assert "valueError"  etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have the easiest time if you use a testing package such as unittest, see this post for how to do that: [How do you test that a Python function throws an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129507/how-do-you-test-that-a-python-function-throws-an-exception)

But if you don't want to use any testing packages, you can do the following (essentially converting the absence of a ValueError into an AssertionError and doing nothing if you get a ValueError):

```
def test():
    data = get_time_zone("sun/10-21 tz:US/Eas2tern")

try:
    test()
    raise AssertionError
except ValueError:
    pass
```