# What's the correct way using pytest to assert that the expression raises an Exception?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to add some unit tests to make sure that the correct Error is being thrown (my function either throws `KeyError` or `RuntimeError`).

I've tried `assert func(bad_param) == KeyError` and `assert isinstance(func(bad_param), KeyError)` but neither of these are correct, how am I supposed to write unit tests for this / what's the correct way to assert that this function, when passed a bad parameter, will raise the correct Exception?

EDIT: I'm NOT using the `unittest` library, I'm asking about purely the `assert` function that comes with Python std lib (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you test that a Python function throws an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129507/how-do-you-test-that-a-python-function-throws-an-exception)

Comment: @maciek97x sorry I should've clarified that I'm not using the unittest library

Comment: Reopening because the linked question was not specific to *pytest*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [pytest.raises](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-raises) context manager:

```py
with pytest.raises(ExpectedErrorType):
    unit_under_test()
```

See [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions) for more details.

I haven't found any example in the docs that would explain how to expect multiple exception types, but you can do that manually by inspecting the exception info object:

```py
with pytest.raises(Exception) as exc_info:
    unit_under_test()

assert issubclass(exc_info.type, (KeyError, RuntimeError))

# alternative more strict assertion
assert exc_info.type in (KeyError, RuntimeError)
```

Answer (score 3):

I already done something like this and I used `try ... except` statement :

```py
try:
    # Code to test
except KeyError:
    assert True
assert False
```

Here is a minimal working example (for *pytest*-like unitary test) :

```py
def fun():
    raise KeyError

def test():
    try:
        fun()
    except KeyError:
        assert True
        return
    assert False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try except` to catch exception like

```py
def foo():
    raise ValueError
    
rightExceptionRaised = False
try:
    foo()
except ValueError:
    rightExceptionRaised = True
except:
    pass

assert rightExceptionRaised
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Refer to post written by @plamut

I found an answer that might be more aligned with how `pytest` intended to check for it!

```
def foo():
    raise KeyError

def test_foo_error():
    with pytest.raise(KeyError)
        foo()
```