# testing class init method with unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, testing

I'm learning how to use unittest in python. I have a class that receives a pandas dataframe in it's init method.

```
class GenericClass:

    def __init__(self, data):
        
        if not (isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame) or isinstance(data, pd.Series)):
            raise ValueError(f'The object {data} must be a pd.DataFrame or a pd.Series')
        
        self.data = data
```

I've created a file called `test.py`. And in this file i'll test the methods of `GenericClass`.

```
import unittest
from file import GenericClass

class TestHistan(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_input(self):
        # no idea on how to implement this
```

My question is, how do i make a test function that tests the inputs passed on the init method of the generic Class?

Comment: What do you mean *"tests the inputs"*? What does the class *do* with that attribute? At the very least you want a test that invalid inputs get rejected and a test that valid ones don't.

Comment: Good question. Does this answer it? [How do you test that a Python function throws an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3166985/1766544)

Comment: @KennyOstrom, Yes!!, thank you