# How to test assertRaised with arguments correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, exception, typeerror, python-unittest

I am trying to test (using unittest.TestCase) that a `ValueError` exception is raised when an invalid value is passed to the deposit method but the test is failing when it being is raised. I've stepped through the test in the debugger and it does reach the `raise ValueError` line but the test still fails for some reason.
I've even tried raising and asserting with other exceptions and the test still fails.

[Here is a debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVbTb.png)

My method:

```
    def deposit(self, amount):
        if (not isinstance(amount, float)) and (not isinstance(amount, int)):
            raise ValueError
```

My test:

```
    def test_illegal_deposit_raises_exception(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.account.deposit("Money"))
```

I then thought that perhaps it was failing becasue the exception had not yet been caught.
So I added a method in my object's class to call the `deposit` method catch the `ValueError` Exception.

```
    def aMethod(self):
        try:
            self.deposit("Money")
        except ValueError:
            print("ValueError was caught")
```

However, now the test failed because I am getting a `TypeError` Exception instead. [Here is an other debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xw8w.png)

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Could someone explain why I am getting a `TypeError` Exception instead of the `ValueError` Exception which I've raised?

Comment: The method returns the value None, not an error (since you caught it), reraise the error after the print (`raise ValueError`). That should at least remove the `TypeError`.

Comment: You're right, if I re-raise the Value error after `print("ValueError was caught")` the correct `ValueError` is raised when I step through in the debugger. In that case, I should not use the `aMethod` method to test and use the `deposit` method to test right? That means I still have to figure out why the test is failing even though the correct exception is being raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/129610/13487763) by Daryl Spitzer I was able to get it working.

[Python docs for assertRaises()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) - Since `assertRaises()` calls the `deposit()` method provided, I needed to provide the call arguments in the `assertRaises()` arguments - instead of in the `deposit()` method call.

The ***correct*** way to test the Exception is raised:

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.account.deposit, "Money")
```

The ***wrong*** way:

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.account.deposit("Money"))
```