# Test if ValidationError was raised . Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I want to test if an exception was raised how can I do that?

In my file.py I have this function:

//file.py

```
 def unlink(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.state in ('progress', 'done'):
                raise ValidationError(_('Error!!)) 
        return super(MyClass, self).unlink()
```

//test_file.py

```
 my_obj.button_validate()
 my_obj.unlink()
```

When adding : my_obj.unlink() in the function ,
I got the output in log like  this:

```
  raise ValidationError(_('Error!!'))
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: Error!!
```

How can I add test if the validation error is shown or not ?

Answer (score 0):

This question might be a duplicate, consider the solution brought [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129507/how-do-you-test-that-a-python-function-throws-an-exception) by Moe:

> Use TestCase.assertRaises (or TestCase.failUnlessRaises) from the
> unittest module, for example:
>
> ```
> import mymod
>
> class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
>     def test1(self):
>         self.assertRaises(SomeCoolException, mymod.myfunc)
> ```