# How to create a test case in python which passes if an exception is raised?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

My code tests if the inputted email and username are the same and raises an error if they are not. I am trying to test the code and it should pass if an exception is raised but I get the exception but the test still fails.
Code:

```
def is_valid_email(email, cognitoUsername):
    if email != cognitoUsername:
        print("User email invalid")
        raise Exception("Username and Email address must be the same")
    print("User email valid")
    return True
```

Test:

```
self.assertEqual(lambda_function.is_valid_email("test@email.com", "test@email.com"), True)
self.assertRaises(Exception, lambda_function.is_valid_email("test@email.com", "test"))
```

Error:

```
email = 'test@email.com', cognitoUsername = 'test'

    def is_valid_email(email, cognitoUsername):
        if email != cognitoUsername:
            print("User email invalid")
>           raise Exception("Username and Email address must be the same")
E           Exception: Username and Email address must be the same

../lambda_function.py:32: Exception




============================== 1 failed in 0.53s ===============================

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test code should call `assertRaises()` with a callable:

```py
self.assertRaises(Exception, lambda: lambda_function.is_valid_email("test@email.com", "test"))
```

The other option is to use `with` like this:

```py
with self.assertRaises(Exception):
    lambda_function.is_valid_email("test@email.com", "test")
```

Comment: Thank you! is it possible to only pass if the Exception has a message, Exception("Username and Email address must be the same")?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3166985)