# How to assert for exceptions with python library unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, try-catch, python-unittest

I have a dummy funtion to try exceptions:

```
def fun(n):
    try:
        if n <1:
            raise ValueError
        return 1
        except:
            pass
```

In my unit test I use:

```
import  unittest
class TestFibonnacci(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_values(self):
        self.assertEqual(fun(1),1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, fun(-1))
```

However I'm unable to get an answer I actually get:

An exception occurred
E....
ERROR: test_values (**main**.TestFibonnacci)

Traceback (most recent call last):
The traceback here

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Ran 1 tests in 0.001s

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the signature for `assertRaises`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

Comment: FYI, likely just pasted incorrectly , but your `except` is not properly indented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you test that a Python function throws an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129507/how-do-you-test-that-a-python-function-throws-an-exception)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `fun(-1)` immediately, rather than letting `self.assertRaises` call it, so that it *can* catch the exception.

You have to pass the function and its arguments separately.

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, fun, -1)
```

Alternatively, you can use `assertRaises` as a context manager.

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
    fun(-1)
```

The `with` statement captures the exception raised by `fun` and provides it to the `__exit__` method of the value returned by `assertRaises`.

Comment: Alternatively, there is the context-manager approach which I personally like

Comment: You are right I passed this as a parameter, thanks I'm going to accept your response.