# How to test exception part in unnitest python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest.mock

I want to test the exception part of my code.

```
def main():
    try:
        logger.info("Ejecución planificada proceso Mae_CIL")
        a = ObjectA()
        a.method()
        logger.info("Success")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error: %s" % e)


@mock.patch.object(ObjectA, 'method')
def test_main(self, mock_method):
    # Case 1: Success
    mock_method.return_value = None
    main()
    self.assertEqual(1, 1)

    # Case 2: Test Exception
    mock_method.return_value = Exception
    self.assertRaises(Exception, main)
```

The Case 1 test the main method. And the Case 2 test the exception but the test fail with this message `'Exception: Exception not raised by main'`

How can i test the exception part??

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129507/how-do-you-test-that-a-python-function-throws-an-exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, just setting `return_value` to an exception doesn't cause that exception to be raised.  That's because an exception is *not* a return--it's a completely different execution context that almost by definition means your function does *not* return.  It's also possible to write a function that returns an exception object (or class as in your example).

You want [`Mock.side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect).