# Python unittest that at least one exception is raised

Tags: python, unit-testing, error-handling, python-unittest

Is there a way to get `unittest` standard library to check for multiple exceptions?

Obviously `assertRaises` works for a single exception: [How do you test that a Python function throws an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129507/how-do-you-test-that-a-python-function-throws-an-exception)

But I want to test whether **at least one** error is raised. This feels right, but is not correct:

```py
with self.assertRaises(StatisticsError, ZeroDivisionError):    # Test one or the other?
  my_list_mean([])
```

---

Full MRE: a "mean" function may raise a `ZeroDivisionError` or a `StatisticsError` depending on the implementation. I want to assert that this raises one or the other:

```py
from statistics import mean, StatisticsError
import unittest

def my_list_mean(lof):
    # return sum(lof) / len(lof)    # ZeroDivisionError
    return mean(lof)                # StatisticsError

class TestMultipleWaysToComputeMean(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_zero_division_or_statistics_error(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError):
            _ = my_list_mean([])

if __name__ == "__main__":  unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an actual tuple. Right now, you are passing `StatisticsError` as an exception and `ZeroDivisionError` as a callable that might produce a `StatisticsError`.

```
with self.assertRaises((StatisticsError, ZeroDivisionError)):
    my_list_mean([])
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html?highlight=unittest#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

> Test that an exception is raised when `callable` is called with any positional or keyword arguments that are also passed to `assertRaises()`. The test passes if `exception` is raised, is an error if another exception is raised, or fails if no exception is raised. **To catch any of a group of exceptions, a tuple containing the exception classes may be passed as `exception`.**

Comment: Nice, I feel a little silly for not trying to pass a tuple sooner. Do you know if this behavior is documented somewhere? The documentation covers the single exception case, but I didn't see anything like your solution: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

Comment: It's documented, but they don't show an example of doing so.