# Tests succeed, still get traceback

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm using Python's `unittest` library and all the tests succeed, but I still get a traceback and I can't understand how I can fix the problem.

```
........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 8 tests in 0.020s

OK

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\bloomfilter\test_bloomfilter.py", line 85, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "C:\Programming\PythonX86\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "C:\Programming\PythonX86\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 231, in runTests
    sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
SystemExit: False
>>>
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79754/unittest-causing-sys-exit) help any?  [For example, passing exit=False to main.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears that you are running in the Python shell, which catches exceptions for you so you can continue debugging.  If you had been running from the command line, the line

```
sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
```

would have exited your program with an exit code of 0, which indicates success (this might be counterintuitive if you're unfamiliar with how programs interact with the shell).  Since you're running in the interpreter, however, the exception is caught.

I would suggest that there is nothing wrong with your program or your tests.  The unittests framework probably just didn't expect to be run interactively!

Answer (score 21):

To avoid the end of execution traceback:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(exit=False)
```

Comment: elegant, concise, precise.

Answer (score 7):

end your unittest file with:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        unittest.main()
    except SystemExit as inst:
        if inst.args[0] is True: # raised by sys.exit(True) when tests failed
            raise
```

Comment: You shouldn't check for `is True` - should just delete that part. Instead of all of this, though, you should instead provide `exit=False`...

Answer (score 3):

## `sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())`

I ran into this when I assumed my `__main__.py` in my Python package would always have the `__name__`, `"__main__"` - but when I ran my unittests through discovery there, I found that they would be executed but with a different `__name__` - `"package.__main__"`.

Therefore I did need the following in my `__main__.py` just like in simple Python scripts:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

instead of just

```
main()
```

If the `main` is `unittest.main`, call it with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(exit=False)
```

if you want the process to stick around in interactive mode if you're calling

```
python -im package_name
```

If you're using:

```
python -m unittest discover
```

then I don't think `exit=False` should matter.

Comment: The most complete and useful answer here. Man I hate how late answers get such a raw deal.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're using to run these tests, it's catching the SystemExit exception and printing the traceback. When you write code that catches exceptions, you should take care to not catch exceptions that you don't actually want to catch, like `SystemExit` (raised by `sys.exit()` to end the program) and usually `KeyboardInterrupt` (raised by control-C.)