# Unittest failed in Python IDE PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I tried to make a simple unittest in Python, but I don't know why the test failed.
I have made three files:

- **name_function.py** in which I have a function that receive two parameters (**first name, last name**) and return the concatenated name.

```
        def get_formatted_name(first, last):
            full_name = first + ' ' + last
            return full_name.title()
```

- **names.py** in which the user is asked to enter the first name and last name or **q** to quit. After that the function **get_formatted_name** is called and concatenated name is printed.

```
        from name_function import get_formatted_name
    
        print("\n Enter 'q' at any time to quit.")
        while True:
            first = input("\n Please give me a first name : ")
            if first == 'q':
                break
            last = input("\n Please give me a second name : ")
            if last == 'q':
                break
    
        formatted_name = get_formatted_name(first, last)
        print("\n\t Neatly formatted name : " + formatted_name + '.')
```

- **test_name_function.py** where the function is tested.

```
        import unittest  
        from name_function import get_formatted_name  
 
        class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):  
            def test_first_last_name(self):  
                formatted_name = get_formatted_name('Clint', 'Eastwood')  
                self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'Clint Eastwood')  

        unittest.main()
```

- In this window, I run **cmd** command (see attach **Capture_1**).
- In **cmd** I run the command (see attach **Capture_2** and **Capture_3**).
- I don't understand where is my mistake? In Capture_3 see what I obtain when I run the test.
- I use Python 3.7.2 and the IDE Python that I use is PyCharm.

[Capture_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T893B.png)
[Capture_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz0YV.png)
[Capture_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su3Dp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good to me. I ran it on my machine and it works great. The only thing I noticed is `python -m unittest` does not find your test. A quick workaround would be to add the following at the end of your unittest file.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Then, you can run it with the following command. `python test_name_function.py`

Comment: I think the problem is that without the guard, unittest.main() is being called again when the test file is imported and is doing a `sys.exit(1)` internally which results in the error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about PyCharm specifically, here's all you need for that:

- remove the last line from your unit test file: `unittest.main()`
- or do what @Zykerd suggested and turn it into

This:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

- rightclick the test in PyCharm and select `Run Unittests in test_name_function`

Both work (i.e. without the call to main, or with the call behind the main name check.

Comment: Thank you Grismar.

Comment: You're welcome - if the answer answered your question, please accept it with the checkmark so the question is marked answered.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is assumed that you are running on the interactive interpreter and at the point of the exception it fails with a SystemExit. However, Like mentioned in the comment from @Zykerd the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

above would solve this problem by assuming that the script is being run from the command line instead of interactive interpreter.

Cheers!

Please check here for further explanation : [Tests succeed, still get traceback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202772/tests-succeed-still-get-traceback)